# A vision for deep learning of Calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation, math-software

I graduated with a bachelor's degree in mathematics in 12 years ago. Then I started working as a professional computer programmer. So now I can use computer and applications like MATLAB.

I want to return to the world of mathematics; try, understand and see inside it with using technology. I think I have to start with calculus again and deep in it.
Now I look for a map which includes list of free PDF files to help me to achieve to that goal also for open source applications to help me see more things after images in PDF files  (my English listening is poor so I do not look for videos)

Comment: If you want to go deep, study real analysis. You already got that far in your degree, right?

Comment: @user4894 You are OK! But it seems I have forgotten basic theorem and examples which will be necessary for good understanding of real analysis.

Comment: The phrase `deep learning' in the title suggests computer algorithms  (automated systems) that can learn calculus and problem-solving, and you start by saying you are a programmer ... I thought I was about to get enlightened with some vision of yours :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a 2 volume work on mathematical analysis which I would highly recommend, given your background. It covers everything in a standard calculus course and a bit more, but is written in a more formal, rigorous style, suitable for a mathematically mature reader. I personally sought it out because I wanted a more rigorous reference for calculus than the typical standard texts and am very pleased with it.

It is Mathematical Analysis I and II by Vladimir A. Zorich, it can be found online at: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich1.pdf and http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~okra/2011-MathIV/Zorich2.pdf

Comment: OK! +1 for your suggested book. But do you have any propose for using computer and programming skills for touching mathematics?

Comment: Computers are extremely useful for studying mathematics because they can remove the need to carry out gratuitously tedious computations the hard way (by hand). They can also be used to create wonderful visualizations which can help with understanding things. I've personally made extensive use of a program called GAP for group theory research, no way I could've done some of what I did without it.

Comment: Link doesn't work.